# Sharepoint password change

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am a Sharepoint newbie, but ironically I am a Sharepoint Administrator right now. In my company we have around 200 employees. I created accounts for all of them, but I need to help them change their passwords as they prefer to use their favorite passwords. I was just wondering: is there any way they can change their passwords by themselves?

Perhaps this is just a dumb question, but I need help from your guys.

Comment: Lee: Listen, you should really make clear that you are working for that boosting company. You have beeen running around forums online and 'casually' recommending your products but contributing little else. Are you trying to fish for a 'recommendation' or will your alter ego recommend a product?

Comment: Bjørn - Thanks for pointing lee.sharepoint out.
Lee.SharePoint - If you want anyone to take anything you say seriously, you should put a disclaimer in your posts that says you work for SharePointBoost.  

Imagine my surprise when you found the solution to your own question at SharePointBoost!

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [SharePoint User Change Password](http://www.codeplex.com/userchangepassword):

> **Project Description**:
>
> - Web part for use change password user
>
> **System requierement**:
>
> - FrameWork 3.5
> - MOSS 2007 or WSS 3.0
>
> **Proprieties**:
>
> - user can change domain password
> - write domain policy, when new password is wrong
> - show/hide text in textbox
> - Function User must change password at next logon

I hope this helps